# What is band number for SIGPOLL?

Tags: c, unix, signals

```
struct siginfo { 

  int    si_signo;  /* signal number */
  int    si_errno;  /* if nonzero, errno value from <errno.h> */ 
  int    si_code;   /* additional info (depends on signal) */ 
  pid_t  si_pid;    /* sending process ID */ 
  uid_t  si_uid;    /* sending process real user ID */ 
  void  *si_addr;   /* address that caused the fault */ 
  int    si_status; /* exit value or signal number */ 
  long   si_band;   /* band number for SIGPOLL */ 
  /* possibly other fields also */ 

};
```

I do not understand `si_band`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Linux manpage for [`sigaction`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), you'll see that:

> - `SIGPOLL/SIGIO` fills in `si_band` and `si_fd`.  The `si_band` event is a bit mask
>          containing the same values as are filled in the revents field by [poll(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html).
>          The `si_fd` field indicates the file descriptor for which the I/O event
>          occurred.

The explanation for what that bitmask means can be found in the linked man page - essentially, it tells the signal handler what type of event triggered the signal (and in Linux at least, you also get the corresponding file descriptor.)

I'm not sure how portable this is. `si_band` seems to be in POSIX, but not `si_fd`. Reference: [POSIX `<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html), [POSIX `poll(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/poll.html)

Answer (score 1):

A process can ask for SIGPOLL signals in order to implement asynchronous I/O. From the [man page of sigactions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html):

> `SIGPOLL`/`SIGIO` fills in si_band and si_fd.  The si_band event is a
>   bit mask containing the same values as are filled in the revents field
>   by poll(2).

`revents` describes the types of the events that happened and lead to `SIGPOLL` being sent. The [man page of poll](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html), describes it in detail:

> The field revents is an output parameter, filled by the kernel with
>   the events that actually occurred. The bits returned in revents can
>   include:

```
POLLIN There is data to read.

POLLPRI
        There is urgent data to read (e.g., out-of-band data on TCP
        socket; pseudoterminal master in packet mode has seen state
        change in slave).

POLLOUT
        Writing now will not block.

POLLRDHUP (since Linux 2.6.17)
        Stream socket peer closed connection, or shut down writing half
        of connection.  The _GNU_SOURCE feature test macro must be
        defined (before including any header files) in order to obtain
        this definition.

POLLERR
        Error condition (output only).

POLLHUP
        Hang up (output only).

POLLNVAL
        Invalid request: fd not open (output only).
```